# java get name of default mail programm

Tags: java

is it possible to get the name of the default mail client im using (thunderbird,outlook etc)?
desktop.mail() opens the default mail client. But where does java read which is the default mail client?

Sincerely

Comment: I'd presume that'd be a concern outside of Java; send it a `mailto` link and let the configured mail client on the OS handle it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

i can get the registry vaue of the default mail client:

```
   package side_pakets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Read_Win_Registry
{
    String output;
    String input;
    String location = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Clients\\Mail";
    /**
     * 
     * @param location
     *            path in the registry
     * @param /ve returns default registry values
     * 
     */
    public String readRegistry(String location)
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "reg query " + location + " /ve ");

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            reader.start();
            process.waitFor();
            reader.join();
            output = reader.getResult();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // return null;
        }
        return output;

    }

    static class StreamReader extends Thread
    {
        private InputStream is;
        private StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        public StreamReader(InputStream is)
        {
            this.is = is;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
                    sw.write(c);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

}
```